# How do I take a value from a variable in a function and use it in another function in C?

Tags: c, function

I am  trying to deal out some cards in my program, the thing that I don't know, is to take the value from a function and pass it into my other function without using a global variable.

Right now, I am so stuck in my program and I can't get anywhere..

I've written a comment below where my problem is. Hope someone have a solution to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIAMONDS 0
#define CLUBS 1
#define HEARTS 2
#define SPADES 3
#define COLOR_SIZE 13
#define NR_OF_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13
#define ACE 1

struct Card
{
    int suit;
    int value;
    int *sum;
};

void player1(struct Card* deck);
void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck);
void swapCards(struct Card *cardA, struct Card *cardB);
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck);

//==================================================================
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //struct Card deck[DECK_SIZE];      //Statically allocated array
    struct Card * deck; //Dynamically allocated array
    int index;
    int suit_index;

    deck = (struct Card *)malloc(sizeof(struct Card) * DECK_SIZE);
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    /* Initiera kortleken */
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++)
        {
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }
    shuffleCards(deck);
    player1(deck);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
//==================================================================

void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 11;
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            cardDeck[i].value = 10;
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value);
            break;
        }

        printf("of ");
        switch (cardDeck[i].suit)
        {
        case DIAMONDS: printf("Diamonds ");
            break;
        case HEARTS: printf("Hearts ");
            break;
        case CLUBS: printf("Clubs ");
            break;
        case SPADES: printf("Spades ");
            break;
        default: printf("Something went wrong!! ");
            break;
        }
        printf("\n");
        sum += cardDeck[i].value;
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void swapCards(struct Card * cardA, struct Card *cardB)
{
    struct Card temp;
    temp = *cardA;
    *cardA = *cardB;
    *cardB = temp;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % 52]);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void player1(struct Card* deck) {
  int sum = 0;
  printCards(deck);

  // Insert code here
}
```

My idea in the last function is to use a variable as above, `sum`, and sum up all the cards, so if I call `printcards(deck)` three times, I want to sum it up all times.

How could this be done?

Comment: functions can `return` a value..

Comment: store the return value of printcards() in sum .

Comment: return anything but `void`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I take a value from a variable in a function and use it in another function in C ?

**Generally**, you could pass and return it as a pointer, to the wanted function. Function signature should be something like:

```
variable_type* function (variable_type* modified_variable);
```

and then called like:

```
new_value = function(&modified_variable);
```

where the ampersand `&` signifies that change will be made.

**In your case**, you could do it by *returning by value* and simply modify your `void printCards(struct Card *cardDeck)` to:

```
int printCards(struct Card *cardDeck) {

    // adding a last line that returns the accumulated sum
    return sum;
}
```

and then use it in your function like so:

```
void player1(struct Card* deck) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum = printCards(deck);
}
```

Comment: Could I have a brief comment regarding the down vote, please?

Comment: But when im trying to print the value of sum in the function player1 like "printf("%d", sum) it still gives me 0.

Comment: @William hart Check the value of `sum` within `printCards()`, make sure you return it at the end and out of any loops. Then check it in `player1()` after you call `printCards()`.